# Getting count for each duplicate entry in XML using xmlSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy, grails-2.0, xmlslurper

I have to count the appearance of each  invalid number (BTNumber) appeared in XML. I am using groovy XmlSlurper() .Please suggest how to count the number and count (as many times it is in xml)

for example-

```
   BTNumber     | count
 ----------------------------------
   2205867438   |   2
   78124614     |   3
```

XML code is as under -

```
<Results>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>2205867438
</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>2461253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:50:04.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>2205867438</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>2461253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:50:18.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>2201159526</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>1111253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:53:07.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>1011159526</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>1111253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:53:18.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
</Results>
 <Results>
  <Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>78124614</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>78124614</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>7812461400</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>MyNetwork</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 10:18:50.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>78124614</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>78124614</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>7812461400</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>MyNetwork</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 15:35:31.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>78124614</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>78124614</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>7812461400</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>MyNetwork</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 15:36:59.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
 </Results>
```

Please suggest if anything else is easier and quicker than XMLSlurper .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your xml has repeated `<Results>`. Do you need that?

You can use something like below to get a map of unique `id` and corresponding `count`:

```
def xmlObj = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def btNumbers = xmlObj.Row.collect{it.BTNumber} 
def countMap = btNumbers.unique(false).collectEntries{btNumber-> 
    [btNumber, btNumbers.count(btNumber)]
}
```

Where `xml` is your xml element mentioned in question.

```
<Results>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>2205867438</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>2461253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:50:04.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>2205867438</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>2461253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:50:18.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>2201159526</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>1111253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:53:07.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
<Row>
    <DialedCountry>001</DialedCountry>
    <BTNumber>1011159526</BTNumber>
    <CPNumber>0000000000</CPNumber>
    <DialedNumber>1111253052</DialedNumber>
    <Wireless>1</Wireless>
    <CarrierCode>customer1</CarrierCode>
    <DateStamp>2013-03-24 11:53:18.0</DateStamp>
</Row>
</Results>
```